# Spyder 4.1.3 always crashes after a few seconds

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have a problem with Spyder after updating it from 3.2.4 to 4.1.3 with

```
conda update spyder
```

The app didn't launch anymore and when I started it from the command prompt I got an error saying

> File "C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\widgets\debugging.py", line 22, in 
> from IPython.core.inputtransformer2 import TransformerManager ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython.core.inputtransformer2'

So I installed ipython using

```
conda install iptyhon
```

If I now click on the spyder app on my desktop the app won't even open. If I type into the command prompt:

```
spyder
```

the app opens but crashes after a few seconds. I am using Anaconda 5.0.1 and python 3.6.3. Unfortunately I don't get an error message or anything so I am quite lost now...

As I am quite new to programming I am not sure what other information could help to solve this problem so I am sorry for the vague question. Any help to find the reason or even a solution to this problem is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have the latest version of anaconda and installation using `conda update spyder` is constricted by `anaconda -> requires spyder==4.0.1=py37_0`. I guess the option is to downgrade to 4.0.1 using `conda install spyder=4.0.1`. If this doesn't help, try to reinstall Anaconda. Actually, the Spyder maintainer [recommends](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/11041#issuecomment-608556060):

> It's usually better to use a new conda env to try major Spyder versions, instead of updating things in the base env.